# NicEdit Error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, nicedit

I'm using the NicEdit WYSIWYG plugin on my site.

It's come to my attention that when NicEdit is instantiated in Chrome, the following Javascript error is generated:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'createRange'
```

This doesn't stop the plugin from working, but I would like to prevent this if possible.  Here is the offending method:

```
getRng : function() {
        var s = this.getSel();
        if(!s) { return null; }
        return (s.rangeCount > 0) ? s.getRangeAt(0) : s.createRange();
}
```

NicEdit seems to be pretty much dead as a project, which is why I am asking this question here instead of over at the NicEdit forums.  I am hoping that someone knows of a 'quickfix' to this problem.  In all other respects NicEdit works well for me, so I am reluctant to change over to a different WYISWYG plugin just yet...

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Answer (score 24):

The problem is that the implementation of the selection object for Webkit does not define a `createRange( )` method.  That method seems to be [specific to Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536394%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  For Webkit and [Gecko DOM implementations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createRange), the `createRange( )` method is defined on the `document` object.  With this knowledge, the fix for `getRng( )` becomes:

```
getRng : function() {
    var s = this.getSel();
    var rng;        

    if(!s) { return null; } 
    if (s.rangeCount > 0) {
        rng = s.getRangeAt(0);
    } else if ( typeof s.createRange === 'undefined' ) {
        rng = document.createRange();
    } else {
        rng = s.createRange(); 
    }       
    return rng;
 },
```

I encountered this as I was evaluating a number of rich text editors for an upcoming project and had to create a sample page with nicEdit.

Answer (score 16):

The version at https://github.com/danishkhan/NicEdit contains this and other bugfixes.

This particular fix: https://github.com/danishkhan/NicEdit/commit/efa6a1e8867b745b841157e919a0055cb626d2c4

Comment: Thanks! Anyone contacted the author to have these fixes merged?

Answer (score 4):

Same code, written in nicEdit current design:

```
getRng : function() {
    var s = this.getSel();
    if(!s) { return null; }
    return (s.rangeCount > 0) ? s.getRangeAt(0) : (typeof s.createRange == 'undefined') ? document.createRange() : s.createRange();
},
```